# How to publish .netCore DIFF to RaspberryPi from Visual Studio Community?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-buster, c#

I use .netCore 3.1 and Raspbian buster.

For the moment I build the .netCore 3.1 solution via this command :

```
dotnet publish -r linux-arm ../MySolution.sln
```

Then I publish it with SSH and Putty

```
pscp -scp -r -pw MYPASSWORD bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1 pi@***.***.***.***:MySolution
```

It takes a lot of time to build all the solution and then send all the dll/symbols to the raspberry.

Is there a way to publish only the diff to the raspberryPi to accelerate the development/debug experience?

Comment: If my answer helped, I'd be grateful if you posted the details: which command increased the performance and by how much.

Comment: I will try it in the next two days. I keep you inform.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I added an answer to the question. I am now able to use rsync to deploy only the diff to the raspberryPi. For the moment I only have the rsync solution (not the incremental build) And it takes only 10 seconds to deploy instead of (5-10mins). Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To speed up the first command, you should enable incremental builds. I'm not familiar with `MSbuild`, but there seems to be a [howto](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-build-incrementally?view=vs-2019) in the MS docs. Apparently, you need to make sure the inputs and outputs for each target are specified in the project file.

The second part is essentially a copy command, which can be accelerated by using an incremental copy tool such as [`rsync`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync).

Answer (score 1):

To answer to the second part, I use rsync to deploy only the diff to the raspberryPi. I still build all the file since I haven't been able yet to set an incremental build for linux-arm.

Thanks to [@Dmitry Grigoryev](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/33476/dmitry-grigoryev) for the idea

**This way we may deploy with a script that takes only 10 seconds instead of 5-10 minutes.**

Here are the steps to do it with visual studio community & windows 10:

1. [Install Windows Subsystem for linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) (I use Ubuntu, any other linux distribution should work)
2. Set your user as a super user on your WSL env (Ubuntu):

   `sudo nano /etc/sudoers.d/myusername`

   `myusername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`
3. Install sshpass on your WSL env (Ubuntu):

   `sudo apt-get install sshpass`
4. Generate an ssh key then copy it to your raspberryPi

   `ssh-keygen (keep all the default directory)`

   `ssh-copy-id pi@RASPBERRY_PI_IP`
5. install rsync to your **WSL** env **&&** to your **raspberryPi** by running :

   `sudo apt-get install rsync`

---

**RaspberryPi only**

*On Debian, you may have a problem with the rrsync.gz that wont extract so run this command:

```
sudo sh -c 'zcat /usr/share/doc/rsync/scripts/rrsync.gz > /usr/local/bin/rrsync'
```

Then make rsync executable by running this command :

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/rrsync
```

---

Then make two bash script to build your app in linux-arm then start wsl to run a deployment script.

1. Build and trigg wsl to start rsync (trigger.sh)

   `echo "BUILDING APP..."`

   `dotnet publish -r linux-arm ../MY_APP.sln`

   `start wsl sh Rsync.sh`

Since windows is not able to run rsync (didn't find how) we are in the obligation to pass the rsync command to the wsl.

2. Rsync.sh

   `PATH_TO_COPY=/mnt/c/DIRECTORY_OF_MY_APP`

   `DESTINATION_PATH=/home/pi/MY_DESTINATION_DIRECTORY`

   `RASPBERRY_IP=MY_RASPBERRY_IP`

   `APP_NAME="MY_APP"`

   `BACKUP_SERVER=pi@$RASPBERRY_IP:`

   `PASSWORD=MY_PASSWORD`

   `sudo sshpass -p $PASSWORD /usr/bin/rsync -avz $PATH_TO_COPY`

   `$BACKUP_SERVER$DESTINATION_PATH`

   `ssh pi@$RASPBERRY_IP sudo killall dotnet`

   `ssh pi@$RASPBERRY_IP <<  EOF`

   ```
   cd MY_DESTINATION_DIRECTORY/netcoreapp3.1/linux-arm/publish/

   sudo dotnet $APP_NAME.dll --urls "http://*:8080"
   ```

   `EOF`

> **Very important :** if you plan to make a bash script to run in wsl, I suggest you to use notepadd++ but set the setting like so :
> **Format:** Unix/OSX
> **Default language:** Shell
> **Encoding:** UTF-8 without BOM
> Because, windows will put some \r\n everywhere and the bash script will break at runtime. **EVEN IF YOU USE NANO IN WSL !!!**

Double click on trigger.sh to deploy your diff to your raspberryPI. Now you can save a LOT of time!